# Replacing the file name in a loop in param file passed to pmcmd

Tags: shell, loops, unix, sed, informatica

I have many filenames listed in a text file, in which each line(file_name) is extracted and is passed to pmcmd. Param file has specific format consisting global parameters such as username, password, domain, filename etc. My problem is how to change the file name in a loop which is passed to pmcmd and triggers the wf to load data from each file listed in text file

Here is my sample script

```
while IFS= read -r var_filename; do
    if [ $p_count -ne 0 ]
    then
    param_file_name=param_file.txt
    out_param=/infa_pmroot/infa_shared/epi/Scripts/claims_dev/test_nv/$param_file_name
    if [ -f $out_param ];  then rm -f $out_param; fi;
    echo $var_filename > $param_file_name
    echo Started executing workflow for $var_filename
    pmcmd startworkflow -sv $Integration_Services -d $Domain -usd $Ldap -u $Username -p $Password -f $Folder -wait wf_workflow_name >>$LogFile 2>>$LogFile
    else 
    echo Check the count of records in PROCESSED_FILE_DETAILS_LOG for the $var_table_name with the "$var_table_name"_FULL_FILE_LIST.txt
    fi
    done < $3"_to_be_processed_file_list.txt"
fi
```

Comment: Where is the filename being passed to `pmcmd`? I don't see `var_filename`, `param_file` or `out_param` being passed to `pmcmd` at all. Is it implicit? What exactly are you having trouble changing here?

Answer (score 0):

In your session, put $InputFileName as the source file name. Now inside your for loop append the parameter to your param file:

```
echo "[Global]"> $param_file_name
echo "\$InputFileName=$var_filename" >> $param_file_name
```

And then pass the parameter file path to `pmcmd`

```
pmcmd startworkflow -sv $Integration_Services -d $Domain -usd $Ldap -u $Username -p $Password -f $Folder -paramfile $param_file_name -wait wf_workflow_name >>$LogFile 2>>$LogFile
```

Comment: Hey Samik, Thanks for your suggestion. I need one more help regarding the same. I'm not able to create parameter file(.prm) from unix. I,m getting Permission denied. Can you please help me with that.